# Не воспроизводится audio на iOS (на iPhone)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, аудио

У меня такая проблема. Есть JS который воспроизводит аудио на сайте и везде не работает, если пользователь заходит с iPhone.
Вот код:

```
 var audio = new Audio();
 audio.src = 'sound.mp3';
 audio.canPlayType('audio/mp3; codecs="vorbis"');
 audio.play();
```

Я читал, что это из-за того, что не указан кодек, но я вроде все указал.
Подскажите что не так?

Comment: а что возвращает вызов ```canPlayType('audio/mp3; codecs="vorbis"')``` ?

Comment: Думаю возможная проблема в том что в основном все Iphone (так же и много других смарфонов) блокируют автоматический запуск Audio. "Пользователь сам должен включить воспроизведение" .....